# Is there a way to determine which view created a block?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views, drupal-blocks

Is there a way to determine which view created a block by looking at the block source?

Comment: I'm suspecting the block I'm looking at isn't even created by a view now, because hoving over it does not reveal the typical edit, export, clone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the block was created by a 3rd party module, template was available in the module itself.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the markup, you can tell by the ids and classes that by default is included on some of the divs.